# Remove text from column if equal to N/A before add more text to the column

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query `UPDATE tblorders SET order_courier_notes = CONCAT(ifnull(order_courier_notes, ''),'$safenote') WHERE order_id = '$product_name'")`

With that query, I am adding text to one SQL column that already has text on it, for example, the value is `Hello world` and I will add the following `how are you?` the text on my column will be `Hello world how are you?` and that part is working.

I need help removing the `N/A` that value is the default value when the column is created, by default it adds the `N/A` I need one way in my query to check if the text in the column `order_courier_notes` is `N/A`, delete the text and do the code that I have at the moment.

Hope you guys can understand what I need.

Comment: Do a search, if the value = N/A, then update. You have the logic already, where exactly is your problem?

Comment: your SQL query/PHP code is prone to SQL injections..

Comment: i geuss just simply `.. WHERE order_id = <id> AND order_courier_notes = 'N/A'` ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland but I want to replace the `N/A` with my `$safenote`, and the second time I add more text it will not have N/A on it and will skip that part and just add the text I want

Comment: Fore example by default it is:
N/A
Then when I add some text it will check if there is N/A, if true it must replace/delete the N/A and place my text, if i add more text and the N/A was already removed it should not remove anything and just add the Text I want

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query could be

```
UPDATE tblorders
SET order_courier_notes = 
   CONCAT(
      IF(order_courier_notes IS NULL OR order_courier_notes='N/A','', order_courier_notes),
      :safenote
   )
WHERE order_id = :product_name
```

I assume 'N/A' is in the column definition, so you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE tblorders MODIFY order_courier_nodes {existing column definition without default}
```

to remove the default value there.